# Removing a Character from string using erase function - C++

Tags: c++, windows-7, codeblocks

I want to erase none number characters in a string, here is my code for doing it:

```
int i=0;
while (num[i]!=NULL)
{
    if (!(num[i]>='0' && num[i]<='9'))
        num.erase(i,1);
    i++;
}
```

think num is e2, then it should be only 2, but it becomes "e". Or if num is 2er4, then it will be 2e4, but it should be 24, how to fix this code?

Comment: A nice thing about C++ is the extensive standard library, which comes with many nice [algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), like for example [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove), which can be used with [`std::isalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems with your code: The first is that your `if` condition is to erase characters if they are digits when you state you want the opposite. The other problem is that when you erase a character, then the length of the string is changed so the index `i` is no longer valid.

Then you loop while the character as position `i` (which may be out of bounds due to the second problem I listed) is not `NULL`. But `NULL` is only used for pointers, if anything you should check against `'\0'` instead. Though I wouldn't recommend that either, as nothing really states that string data inside a `std::string` (which I suppose `num` is) have to be zero-terminated. Instead loop using the string length, or use iterators.

And like I state in my comment, it can be much more simple than your code, by just calling a single function.

Comment: Thanks for your tips, but about if, it points to none digit characters because there is NOT sign (!) behind its condition

Comment: @Stranger Oh, missed that! Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Joachim, the standard library provides you will algorithms that you can trivially use to achieve your objective. The usual approach to remove elements from a standard library container is to use the [*erase remove idiom*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom). The `std::string` class can be considered a container in this case, and the algorithm works as expected. This is a working example, where the `std::isdigit` function is used to determine which elements are removed from the string:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
  std::string s = "abc123def456!!??";
  auto it = std::remove_if(s.begin(),
                           s.end(),
                           [](char c) { return std::isdigit(c);});

  s.erase(it, s.end());

  std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, but erase function is good, there is only one problem with it, for example input is "e2", If I want to erase e then what is the code? is it num.erase(0,1)? it means start from 0 character which is "e" then delete one character after it! the problem is here, I do not want to delete one character after it, I want to start deleting from the pointed character, is erase can do it?

Comment: @Stranger if you want to remove everything that is not a digit, you need `return !std::isdigit(c);`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fix it with Joachim Pileborg Tips, Thank You Man;

```
int i=0;
while (num[i]!=NULL)
{
    if (!(num[i]>='0' && num[i]<='9'))
        {num.erase(i,1); if ((i-1)>=0) i--;}
    else i++;
}
```